# VSCODE GIT asks to Sync changes after pull

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

we have a code in a remote repository. When a colleague do a change in the code and push to the repo, I do PULL in the VSCODE and VSCODE asks me to Sync the changes. But Sync the changes mean I push the code to the repo (with the change that my colleague did).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Dv9.png)

Am I missing something here? My expectation is just to pull the most fresh code from the repo to my computer for further changes, and push it to the repo.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that VSCode is trying to be helpful here, to go above and beyond basic Git. This isn't really a Git issue, it's really a VSCode issue. If you like the things VSCode does here, use them! If not, maybe don't use them / it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the simplest case. You are working away, and you make a commit locally on this branch. Meanwhile, your colleague has also made a commit on this branch and pushed it to the remote repository.

So now your branch is one commit ahead of the remote, because of the commit you made, and at the same time the remote is one commit ahead of you, because of the commit your colleague made. We say that you are *both ahead and behind*.

```
A -- B -- X (remote; X was pushed by your colleage)

A -- B -- Y (you)
```

Now you pull. You already have a commit, so your local Git makes a merge commit. So now you are *two* commits ahead of the remote — the same commit as before, plus the new merge commit.

```
A -- B -- X (remote, unchanged)

A -- B -- Y -- M (you, merge commit)
      \       /
       X ----/
```

So VS Code notices this and offers to let you sync up, pushing those two commits to the remote. If you do, and the push succeeds, now your branch and the remote are exactly in sync — they have the very same commits.